# Airflow Database setup

Tags: mysql, celery, airflow, scaling, airflow-scheduler

Recently we have been facing a lot of issues related to Airflow Database in our setup. One when hit a deadlock (two queries trying to acquire indices on task_instance table) & other when logs indicated 'Too many open connections' from Airflow side. We are using celery executor, whose backend is also same as airflow backend.
Currently we have only one DAG with about 30-40 tasks in parallel and SubDAGs with about 3-4 level nesting. Most of these tasks are lightweight, they make an async microservice call & wait for it to finish (as sensor).
We might have about 15-20 such DAGs running in simultaneously.
Our DB instance is t3.medium.
airflow.cfg file:

```
[core]
# The folder where your airflow pipelines live, most likely a
# subfolder in a code repository
# This path must be absolute
dags_folder = /home/ubuntu/airflow-local-user/airflow_home/dags2

# The folder where airflow should store its log files
# This path must be absolute
base_log_folder = /home/ubuntu/airflow-local-user/airflow_home/logs

# Airflow can store logs remotely in AWS S3, Google Cloud Storage or Elastic Search.
# Users must supply an Airflow connection id that provides access to the storage
# location. If remote_logging is set to true, see UPDATING.md for additional
# configuration requirements.
remote_logging = False
remote_log_conn_id =
remote_base_log_folder =
encrypt_s3_logs = False

# Logging level
logging_level = INFO
fab_logging_level = WARN

# Logging class
# Specify the class that will specify the logging configuration
# This class has to be on the python classpath
# logging_config_class = my.path.default_local_settings.LOGGING_CONFIG
logging_config_class =

# Log format
# Colour the logs when the controlling terminal is a TTY.
colored_console_log = True
colored_log_format = [%%(blue)s%%(asctime)s%%(reset)s] {%%(blue)s%%(filename)s:%%(reset)s%%(lineno)d} %%(log_color)s%%(levelname)s%%(reset)s - %%(log_color)s%%(message)s%%(reset)s
colored_formatter_class = airflow.utils.log.colored_log.CustomTTYColoredFormatter

log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s

# Log filename format
log_filename_template = {{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
dag_processor_manager_log_location = /home/ubuntu/airflow-local-user/airflow_home/logs/dag_processor_manager/dag_processor_manager.log

# Hostname by providing a path to a callable, which will resolve the hostname
# The format is "package:function". For example,
# default value "socket:getfqdn" means that result from getfqdn() of "socket" package will be used as hostname
# No argument should be required in the function specified.
# If using IP address as hostname is preferred, use value "airflow.utils.net:get_host_ip_address"
hostname_callable = socket:getfqdn

# Default timezone in case supplied date times are naive
# can be utc (default), system, or any IANA timezone string (e.g. Europe/Amsterdam)
default_timezone = utc

# The executor class that airflow should use. Choices include
# SequentialExecutor, LocalExecutor, CeleryExecutor, DaskExecutor, KubernetesExecutor
executor = CeleryExecutor

# The SqlAlchemy connection string to the metadata database.
# SqlAlchemy supports many different database engine, more information
# their website
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://username:password@jaguar-mr-mds.cj9zq8oequpw.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/airflow

# The encoding for the databases
sql_engine_encoding = utf-8

# If SqlAlchemy should pool database connections.
sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = True

# The SqlAlchemy pool size is the maximum number of database connections
# in the pool. 0 indicates no limit.
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5

# The maximum overflow size of the pool.
# When the number of checked-out connections reaches the size set in pool_size,
# additional connections will be returned up to this limit.
# When those additional connections are returned to the pool, they are disconnected and discarded.
# It follows then that the total number of simultaneous connections the pool will allow is pool_size + max_overflow,
# and the total number of "sleeping" connections the pool will allow is pool_size.
# max_overflow can be set to -1 to indicate no overflow limit;
# no limit will be placed on the total number of concurrent connections. Defaults to 10.
sql_alchemy_max_overflow = 10

# The SqlAlchemy pool recycle is the number of seconds a connection
# can be idle in the pool before it is invalidated. This config does
# not apply to sqlite. If the number of DB connections is ever exceeded,
# a lower config value will allow the system to recover faster.
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 1800

# How many seconds to retry re-establishing a DB connection after
# disconnects. Setting this to 0 disables retries.
sql_alchemy_reconnect_timeout = 300

# The schema to use for the metadata database
# SqlAlchemy supports databases with the concept of multiple schemas.
sql_alchemy_schema =

# The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
# the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
# on this airflow installation
parallelism = 32

# The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
dag_concurrency = 16

# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True

# The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16

# Whether to load the examples that ship with Airflow. It's good to
# get started, but you probably want to set this to False in a production
# environment
load_examples = False

# Where your Airflow plugins are stored
plugins_folder = /home/ubuntu/airflow-local-user/airflow_home/plugins

# Secret key to save connection passwords in the db
fernet_key = jZLcYYUUpUt8K26A9qlznu4E3yFb_Xn280dxp0yQVwM=

# Whether to disable pickling dags
donot_pickle = False

# How long before timing out a python file import while filling the DagBag
dagbag_import_timeout = 30

# The class to use for running task instances in a subprocess
task_runner = StandardTaskRunner

# If set, tasks without a `run_as_user` argument will be run with this user
# Can be used to de-elevate a sudo user running Airflow when executing tasks
default_impersonation =

# What security module to use (for example kerberos):
security =

# If set to False enables some unsecure features like Charts and Ad Hoc Queries.
# In 2.0 will default to True.
secure_mode = False

# Turn unit test mode on (overwrites many configuration options with test
# values at runtime)
unit_test_mode = False

# Name of handler to read task instance logs.
# Default to use task handler.
task_log_reader = task

# Whether to enable pickling for xcom (note that this is insecure and allows for
# RCE exploits). This will be deprecated in Airflow 2.0 (be forced to False).
enable_xcom_pickling = True

# When a task is killed forcefully, this is the amount of time in seconds that
# it has to cleanup after it is sent a SIGTERM, before it is SIGKILLED
killed_task_cleanup_time = 60

# Whether to override params with dag_run.conf. If you pass some key-value pairs through `airflow backfill -c` or
# `airflow trigger_dag -c`, the key-value pairs will override the existing ones in params.
dag_run_conf_overrides_params = False

# Worker initialisation check to validate Metadata Database connection
worker_precheck = False

# When discovering DAGs, ignore any files that don't contain the strings `DAG` and `airflow`.
dag_discovery_safe_mode = True

[webserver]
# The base url of your website as airflow cannot guess what domain or
# cname you are using. This is used in automated emails that
# airflow sends to point links to the right web server
base_url = http://10.0.1.180:9080

# The ip specified when starting the web server
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0

# The port on which to run the web server
web_server_port = 9080

# Paths to the SSL certificate and key for the web server. When both are
# provided SSL will be enabled. This does not change the web server port.
web_server_ssl_cert =
web_server_ssl_key =

# Number of seconds the webserver waits before killing gunicorn master that doesn't respond
web_server_master_timeout = 120

# Number of seconds the gunicorn webserver waits before timing out on a worker
web_server_worker_timeout = 120

# Number of workers to refresh at a time. When set to 0, worker refresh is
# disabled. When nonzero, airflow periodically refreshes webserver workers by
# bringing up new ones and killing old ones.
worker_refresh_batch_size = 1

# Number of seconds to wait before refreshing a batch of workers.
worker_refresh_interval = 300

# Secret key used to run your flask app
secret_key = temporary_key

# Number of workers to run the Gunicorn web server
workers = 4

# The worker class gunicorn should use. Choices include
# sync (default), eventlet, gevent
worker_class = sync

# Log files for the gunicorn webserver. '-' means log to stderr.
access_logfile = -
error_logfile = -

# Expose the configuration file in the web server
# This is only applicable for the flask-admin based web UI (non FAB-based).
# In the FAB-based web UI with RBAC feature,
# access to configuration is controlled by role permissions.
expose_config = True

# Set to true to turn on authentication:
# https://airflow.apache.org/security.html#web-authentication
authenticate = False

# Filter the list of dags by owner name (requires authentication to be enabled)
filter_by_owner = False

# Filtering mode. Choices include user (default) and ldapgroup.
# Ldap group filtering requires using the ldap backend
#
# Note that the ldap server needs the "memberOf" overlay to be set up
# in order to user the ldapgroup mode.
owner_mode = user

# Default DAG view.  Valid values are:
# tree, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times
dag_default_view = tree

# Default DAG orientation. Valid values are:
# LR (Left->Right), TB (Top->Bottom), RL (Right->Left), BT (Bottom->Top)
dag_orientation = LR

# Puts the webserver in demonstration mode; blurs the names of Operators for
# privacy.
demo_mode = False

# The amount of time (in secs) webserver will wait for initial handshake
# while fetching logs from other worker machine
log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5

# By default, the webserver shows paused DAGs. Flip this to hide paused
# DAGs by default
hide_paused_dags_by_default = False

# Consistent page size across all listing views in the UI
page_size = 100

# Use FAB-based webserver with RBAC feature
rbac = False

# Define the color of navigation bar
navbar_color = #007A87

# Default dagrun to show in UI
default_dag_run_display_number = 25

# Enable werkzeug `ProxyFix` middleware
enable_proxy_fix = False

# Set secure flag on session cookie
cookie_secure = False

# Set samesite policy on session cookie
cookie_samesite =

# Default setting for wrap toggle on DAG code and TI log views.
default_wrap = False

# Send anonymous user activity to your analytics tool
# analytics_tool = # choose from google_analytics, segment, or metarouter
# analytics_id = XXXXXXXXXXX

[celery]
# This section only applies if you are using the CeleryExecutor in
# [core] section above

# The app name that will be used by celery
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor

# The concurrency that will be used when starting workers with the
# "airflow worker" command. This defines the number of task instances that
# a worker will take, so size up your workers based on the resources on
# your worker box and the nature of your tasks
worker_concurrency = 16

# The maximum and minimum concurrency that will be used when starting workers with the
# "airflow worker" command (always keep minimum processes, but grow to maximum if necessary).
# Note the value should be "max_concurrency,min_concurrency"
# Pick these numbers based on resources on worker box and the nature of the task.
# If autoscale option is available, worker_concurrency will be ignored.
# http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-autoscale
# worker_autoscale = 16,12

# When you start an airflow worker, airflow starts a tiny web server
# subprocess to serve the workers local log files to the airflow main
# web server, who then builds pages and sends them to users. This defines
# the port on which the logs are served. It needs to be unused, and open
# visible from the main web server to connect into the workers.
worker_log_server_port = 8793

# The Celery broker URL. Celery supports RabbitMQ, Redis and experimentally
# a sqlalchemy database. Refer to the Celery documentation for more
# information.
# http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#broker-settings
#broker_url = sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
broker_url = pyamqp://username:password@10.0.1.42:5672/

# The Celery result_backend. When a job finishes, it needs to update the
# metadata of the job. Therefore it will post a message on a message bus,
# or insert it into a database (depending of the backend)
# This status is used by the scheduler to update the state of the task
# The use of a database is highly recommended
# http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-result-backend-settings
result_backend = db+mysql://username:password@jaguar-mr-mds.cj9zq8oequpw.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/airflow_celery

# Celery Flower is a sweet UI for Celery. Airflow has a shortcut to start
# it `airflow flower`. This defines the IP that Celery Flower runs on
flower_host = 0.0.0.0

# The root URL for Flower
# Ex: flower_url_prefix = /flower
flower_url_prefix =

# This defines the port that Celery Flower runs on
flower_port = 5555

# Securing Flower with Basic Authentication
# Accepts user:password pairs separated by a comma
# Example: flower_basic_auth = user1:password1,user2:password2
flower_basic_auth =

# Default queue that tasks get assigned to and that worker listen on.
default_queue = default

# How many processes CeleryExecutor uses to sync task state.
# 0 means to use max(1, number of cores - 1) processes.
sync_parallelism = 0

# Import path for celery configuration options
celery_config_options = airflow.config_templates.default_celery.DEFAULT_CELERY_CONFIG

# In case of using SSL
ssl_active = False
ssl_key =
ssl_cert =
ssl_cacert =

# Celery Pool implementation.
# Choices include: prefork (default), eventlet, gevent or solo.
# See:
#   https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency
#   https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html
pool = prefork

[celery_broker_transport_options]
# This section is for specifying options which can be passed to the
# underlying celery broker transport.  See:
# http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-broker_transport_options

# The visibility timeout defines the number of seconds to wait for the worker
# to acknowledge the task before the message is redelivered to another worker.
# Make sure to increase the visibility timeout to match the time of the longest
# ETA you're planning to use.
#
# visibility_timeout is only supported for Redis and SQS celery brokers.
# See:
#   http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-broker_transport_options
#
#visibility_timeout = 21600

[scheduler]
# Task instances listen for external kill signal (when you clear tasks
# from the CLI or the UI), this defines the frequency at which they should
# listen (in seconds).
job_heartbeat_sec = 2

# The scheduler constantly tries to trigger new tasks (look at the
# scheduler section in the docs for more information). This defines
# how often the scheduler should run (in seconds).
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 2

# after how much time should the scheduler terminate in seconds
# -1 indicates to run continuously (see also num_runs)
run_duration = -1

# after how much time (seconds) a new DAGs should be picked up from the filesystem. Original Value : 5
min_file_process_interval = 5 

# How often (in seconds) to scan the DAGs directory for new files. Default to 5 minutes.
dag_dir_list_interval = 5

# How often should stats be printed to the logs
print_stats_interval = 30

# If the last scheduler heartbeat happened more than scheduler_health_check_threshold ago (in seconds),
# scheduler is considered unhealthy.
# This is used by the health check in the "/health" endpoint
scheduler_health_check_threshold = 30

child_process_log_directory = /home/ubuntu/airflow-local-user/airflow_home/logs/scheduler

# Local task jobs periodically heartbeat to the DB. If the job has
# not heartbeat in this many seconds, the scheduler will mark the
# associated task instance as failed and will re-schedule the task.
scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = 300

# Turn off scheduler catchup by setting this to False.
# Default behavior is unchanged and
# Command Line Backfills still work, but the scheduler
# will not do scheduler catchup if this is False,
# however it can be set on a per DAG basis in the
# DAG definition (catchup)
catchup_by_default = True

# This changes the batch size of queries in the scheduling main loop.
# If this is too high, SQL query performance may be impacted by one
# or more of the following:
#  - reversion to full table scan
#  - complexity of query predicate
#  - excessive locking
#
# Additionally, you may hit the maximum allowable query length for your db.
#
# Set this to 0 for no limit (not advised)
max_tis_per_query = 512

# Statsd (https://github.com/etsy/statsd) integration settings
statsd_on = False
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow

# The scheduler can run multiple threads in parallel to schedule dags.
# This defines how many threads will run.
max_threads = 3

authenticate = False

# Turn off scheduler use of cron intervals by setting this to False.
# DAGs submitted manually in the web UI or with trigger_dag will still run.
use_job_schedule = False

#min_file_parsing_loop_time=3600
```

So any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` so we can see the deadlock.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) involved.

Answer (score 2):

We have had deadlocks related to the default autocommit setting of False. Depending on your requirements, this may create unnecessarily long running transactions: if you run multiple statements using the same cursor all executions will be part of a transaction, which increases the risk of a deadlock.

Below an example with an SQL Server hook, but I suspect it will be similar for other hooks.

```
hook = MsSqlHook(mssql_conn_id="detbds")
with hook.get_conn() as conn:
    conn.autocommit = True
    cursor = conn.cursor()
```

This solved / relieved the risk of deadlock in this specific case. Your mileage may vary depending on requirement.